Ubuntu 22.04 sound disappeared
Sound disappeared in Ubuntu 22.04.
The only way I can make the sound work is to start playing a video or music, and switch the "Output device" under System settings manually from Line Out - Built-in Audio to HDMI / DisplayPort - Built-in Audio and then back to Line Out - Built-in Audio.
I used to have two sound volume sliders when clicking on the sound icon in the top right corner and now I see only one.

Thank you! It was indeed the kernel problem. The sound works again after rolling back to an older version. I also used apt-mark hold to prevent that particular kernel version from installing.

Since it worked I wrote an answer, so others may see it. You might mark it as solved there

It may be an kernel/update problem. Roll back to the previous kernel and check it out.
It works means, that either the sound driverdoesn't work with the current kernel, or that version might have a glitch.
